# Comments are getting deleted from web.xml

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, servlets, web.xml

My problem is that, when I insert a new Servlet into a dinamic web project with wizard, the content of the web.xml file is always collapsed:

- Indent tabs are converted into two space;
- Extra white rows are removed;
- Comments are removed.

How can I prevent this, or can I even do something?

Answer (score 1):

To disable eclipse from deleting comments in xml-files::

Look at your Window->Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor -> Typing settings: 
Automatically remove:
clear check-box of: End tags when creating empty self-closing tags

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your eclipse is configured to do so.

Look at your Window->Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor settings

-make sure indent using tabs is selected
-clear all blank lines is unchecked

as for comments being removed, not sure about that one. maybe format comments checkbox.

Comment: Unfortunately the first two of your guesses were set already as you said.